# Kendo UI - Grid with custom editor dropdown grouping issue

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

when i use Kendo ui custom editor dropdownlist with groupable to true to the grid its not working. Its throwing the below error.

I tried the add this groupable attribute to the demo code in (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom), its not working either.  Is it a known bug? could some one help

Unhandled exception at line 27, column 16670 in Scripts/kendo.all.min.js

0x800a03ef - JavaScript runtime error: Expected ']'

Comment: What exactly triggers the error, just adding grouping? The following example seems to work as expected: http://dojo.telerik.com/omOLe

Comment: yeah , It is working their , where do you added ? I added after `editable: true` as `groupable : true`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added groupable:true after editable:true.  this is not working only when i try to do the grouping for  the Category column.  It appears works fine for Product name or Unit price column.